# sharepoint silverlight web part does not work on server

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, lync-2010

I've developed a Lync Silverlight application and it is working on my local machine. Then I needed to add this Silverlight to a Sharepoint site, thus i used Silverlight web part. It is OK on my local Sharepoint site but when i install it to server i could not see the Silverlight and not getting error.

I am using web service on my Silverlight application. I check that server can access to web services. My development environment is Visual Studio 2010 and Lync Server 2010. Also I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Here is what i tried for the solution:

1. Check the whether IIS is configured for xap - OK
2. I tried to install xap file through Sharepoint module, it did not work.
3. I tried to use a visual web part, it did not work.
4. I tried to embed xap file to an HTML page for debugging, there was no error.

Now i am stuck. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Have you cross-verify with which Silverlight sdk version you have developed your silverlight application.

And server is having that version installed?

if it's working fine with your local server then it also works fine with another server.

regards.